# Uluru in Heroes

Tags: symbols, heroes

While Heroes may have gone downhill fast after its second season, the beginning had some great storytelling, often with some augmented reality elements connecting the show to some of the out-of-show lore. In the 9th Wonders comic series, existing within the world of the show, one prominent figure is that of Uluru, some sort of powerful creature (appearing to be a rock monster or something of the kind). Uluru is also the Anangu name of a prominent geological feature in Australia, also known as Ayer's Rock. In the show, 9th Wonders is illustrated by Isaac, who possesses the power of prophecy. Many of his 9th Wonders covers refer to other super-powered characters, or events bound to occur, but Uluru does not appear anywhere in the show except in the comic.

So, the question is, what is the significance (if any) of Uluru, within the context of the show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At San Diego Comic Con 2007:

> When asked if Uluru, the rock monster that graced the cover of an early issue of the comic "9th Wonders," would be making an appearance in the show proper, Kring said the monster only existed in the pages of the comic book.

And that's all that's ever been definitively stated about Uluru. It doesn't represent a person or event, it's just something that exists in the comic.

The graphic novel [Isaac's First Time](http://heroeswiki.com/Isaac%27s_First_Time) has Isaac receive a vision (not heroin introduced; it's not really clear where it came from) of Uluru who asks him "What have you done?", which is repeated several more times by both a woman he meets later and ultimately by himself. Based on that you could argue that Uluru is somehow tied to Isaac's power of foretelling the future, but nothing more has been said.